# The declared parameter 'Search SOLR Core Application Connection String' is not recognized

Tags: sitecore-client, solr

Hi I am installing Sitecore using ARM template and as search service, I am using SOLR.

In the template, I have provided the solrConnectionString as

```
"solrConnectionString":{
      "value": "https://dev-solrXXXXX.com:8983/solr"
    },

xcSolrConnectionString - blank (no entry for this)
"xcSearchMsDeployPackageUrl": {
      "value": "https://XXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/storage/WDP/XP/Sitecore 9.2.0 rev. 002893 (Cloud)_xp1collectionsearch.scwdp.zip"
    }
```

And while I am running the template, its giving an error as below.

```
{

  "code": "DeploymentFailed",

  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.",

  "details": [
    {

      "code": "Conflict",

      "message": "{\r\n  \"status\": \"failed\",\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n    \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'failed'.\",\r\n    \"details\": [\r\n      {\r\n        \"code\": \"Failed\",\r\n        \"message\": \"AppGallery Deploy Failed: 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentXmlException: The declared parameter 'Search SOLR Core Application Connection String' is not recognized.\\r\\n\\r\\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncParameterCollection.LoadFromFile(XPathNavigator nav, String fileName, Boolean ignoreExtraSetParameters)\\r\\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.LoadSetParameters(DeploymentObject deploymentObject, IDictionary`2 setParams, String setParamXmlFile)\\r\\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.AppGalleryPackage.Deploy(String deploymentSite, String siteSlotId, Boolean doNotDelete)\\r\\n   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.WebApi.DeploymentController.&lt;DownloadAndDeployPackage&gt;d__24.MoveNext()'\"\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n}"

    }

  ]

}
```

Can anyone help me out of this?

Comment: Did you check your solr url https://dev-solrXXXXX.com:8983/solr is working?

Comment: Yes, it is wokring properly with SSL certificate

Comment: try by adding the same URL for xcSolrConnectionString as well and let me know if this works.

Comment: xcSolrConnectionString takes the solrConnectionString's data. I don't think it will help out.

Comment: When I am installing Sitecore from azure market place, then it is installing perfectly. Is there anything except solrConnectionString and xcSearchMsDeployPackageUrl?

Comment: Is this is fixed i am also facing same issue?

Comment: Yes..it was done. Please check the path carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SOLR search WDP will be a little bit different.

> "xcSearchMsDeployPackageUrl": {
>         "value": "https://XXXXX.blob.core.windows.net/storage/WDP/XP/Sitecore 9.2.0
>   rev. 002893 (Cloud)_xp1collectionsearch**SOLR**.scwdp.zip"
>       }

That's all.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue(The declared parameter 'Search SOLR Core Application Connection String' is not recognized) can you please let me know is there any work around?

Comment: it was done for me after changing the SOLR WDP path. Check the path carefully once.